# how to print varient value on rail3 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to print some variant value on console or logs then i can check is there something wrong,
i tried puts & print ,i didn't find output info,how to solve this,thanks,i'm new on rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puts and print will output code in the console for code run in the console. A better method usually is to use the built in logging. For logging that you only want recorded in development, you can use the "logger.debug()" method. Just pass in a string as an argument and look for the results in log/development.log

```
logger.debug("Time.now is #{Time.now}")
```

Something like that.